# Difference between node, peer and user in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'd like to read about the difference between these terms: Node, Peer and User.

From what I understand, a **node** is basically a machine which inside is running the HL Fabric binaries and is communicating with other machines belonging to the same network.
A **peer** is the *type* of the node, in particular:

- *Orderer*: the one which put the transactions in a certain order for the insert in the ledger.
- *Endorser*: this type is the one that runs the chaincode and produces the RW sets.
- *Commitment*: a peer that propagates valid transaction among the network.

Finally, a **user** is a subject that has a digital certificate and exists in some organization. More users can work on the same node / peer.

Please tell me if there is something wrong in what I wrote and, eventually, why is that wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your definition of a user is correct. I think the below graphic from the [Hyperledger Fabric paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/3190508.3190538) should be helpful toward understanding the word 'peer'.

- *Node*: Generic term for any type of application that is part of the Fabric network. A node in a Fabric network can be one of three things: Client, Peer or Ordering Service Node (Orderer)
- *Peer*: Every peer maintains a copy of the ledger. The peers execute a consensus protocol to validate transactions, group them into blocks, and build a hash chain over the blocks. A peer may be an *endorser* for a specific chaincode, but doesn't have to be.

  - *Endorser*: Part of every peer. Runs the chaincode and produces the RW sets.
  - *Committer*: Part of every peer. Performs validation of transactions after ordering
  - *Ledger*: Part of every peer. Stores blockchain state and history.
- *Orderer*: Separate instances responsible for reaching consensus on the order of transactions, i.e. Raft based
- *Client*: Submits transaction proposals to peers, specifically those peers that are endorsers for the relevant chaincode
- *User*: Has a valid user certificate issued by an MSP. Creates transactions using a *client* to interact with chaincode.

To gain a thorough understanding of each of these I recommend reading the full paper yourself.

[image]